# CodeIgniter: Adding Dynamic Data to Multiple Views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and have noticed that when I do this:

```
$data1['title']='New Place';
$data2['color']='red';
$this->load->view('header', $data1);
$this->load->view('content', $data2);
```

I can access `$title` from `views/content.php`, but I did not add `$data1` to this second view.

If that's normal, is it more efficent to add ALL the data only to the first loaded view, like the following?

```
$data['title']='New Place';
$data['color']='red';
$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('content');
```

or isn't it important (especially when adding lots of data to the views)?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Yes, because you're loading multiple views together, just supply data to the top view, which should allow you to access it within the content, and if you have one,  the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to separate the data in two arrays. Just one array with all data and sent it to each view. Each view will use the needed variables. your code will be so much clearer than if you split the data and there's no difference in resources consumption.